# Why do cloud functions switch between numeric and alphanumeric execution ids?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Often execution_ids will show strictly numeric execution ids in the log: `1009612003154395`

Other times, execution ids are alphanumeric like: `zjxjkn9mp4p9`

Why are these changing execution id types chosen?  Are they as arbitrary as they seem?  Can I infer anything from them?

Answer (score 2):

An execution ID is just a string that uniquely identifies a single invocation of a function.  That's all it means.  The contents of that string are meaningless, but you can be sure it will be unique for all invocations of a particular type of function.

One documented use of it (the only one I could find) is for view logs coming from that one invocation.  This makes it easier to track how a function executed, without having to sort through a bunch of log lines from other functions.  See the [documentation for logging](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging):

> You can even view the logs for a specific execution:
>
> ```
> gcloud functions logs read FUNCTION_NAME --execution-id EXECUTION_ID
> ```

Comment: Thanks for replying Doug but that doesn't seem to be the case that the IDs are arbitrary. Based on searching our historic logs this is our current understanding:  Execution IDs are unique IDs generated on each invocation of the function and are alphanumeric. Event IDs are unique IDs passed to PubSub triggered functions and are numeric.

Comment: Arbitrary does not mean that the IDs aren't formatted in some way.  The formatting won't help you, however - they still don't contain any actual data, and are used only for uniqueness.